# Select next closest with class

Tags: jquery

I want to make a simple method to hide/show content when a user clicks a radio button. Rather than use ID's over and over, I want to make a more universal selector using classes so I could re-apply it throughout my site.

I think I am not getting outside the parent div (.radio-show) to find .next .radio-show-content?

```
$('.radio-show input:radio').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').next().find('.radio-show-content').fadeToggle(250).toggleClass('hide'); 
});


<div class="radio-show" > 
<label class="radio span1">
    <input type="radio" name="project" value="option1" checked>
    Yes
</label>
<label class="radio span1">
    <input type="radio" name="project" value="option2">
    No
</label>
</div>

<hr />
<div class="radio-show-content"><!-- yes -->
    Show this if Yes
</div>
<div class="radio-show-content hide"><!-- no-->
    Show this if No
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.next` is getting the `<hr>`.  There's no need to go up the DOM tree, really.  You can just use:

```
$(".radio-show-content").fadeToggle(250).toggleClass('hide')
```

*However*, this probably doesn't do what you want in that it does not select a specific `.radio-show-content`.  You can link based on radio button index (get with `.index` and get the `-show-content` with `.eq`), or just use CSS transitions with `.hide` and toggle it consistently.

Comment: ah your right, no need to go up the DOM tree. But what if I want to limit selecting only the NEXT 2 .radio-show-content classes. eg. there are multiple radio pairs on the same page that show/hide specific to the closest .radio-show-content closest to them?

Comment: @simple that sounds pretty complicated .. you would have to link the radio buttons to the radio-content via classes, or use corresponding indices as I described in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try without `.find()`

```
$(this).closest('div').next('.radio-show-content').fadeToggle(250).toggleClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin was written for exactly this. *Disclaimer: I wrote it*

http://techfoobar.com/jquery-next-in-dom/

```
$('.radio-show input:radio').click(function() {
    $(this).nextInDOM('.radio-show-content').fadeToggle(250).toggleClass('hide');
});
```

Comment: NOTE: But in your case, if you have only one element matching `'.radio-show-content'`, just do a simple selector as answered by Explosion Pills. In such a case using the plugin will be an overkill.